# Problem checking pdf flags pdfAnnotation.HasFlag error

Tags: annotations, itext, flags, itext7

I am working on a tool that checks PDF annotations. I am able to check the flags but I am getting a error on one particular flag. What could be the cause?

```
    Public Sub GetComments()

    Dim oComments As New PDFcomments
    Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader("C:\Users\jeee\Desktop\1_3047 - Type 1.pdf")
    Dim pdfdocument As New PdfDocument(reader)


    For i As Integer = 1 To pdfdocument.GetNumberOfPages

        Dim pdfPage As PdfPage = pdfdocument.GetPage(i)
        Dim oAnnotations As IList(Of Annot.PdfAnnotation) = pdfPage.GetAnnotations()


        For Each oAnnotation As Annot.PdfAnnotation In oAnnotations

            Dim oAnnotationSubType As PdfName = oAnnotation.GetSubtype

            If oAnnotationSubType.ToString = "/FreeText" Then
                Debug.Print(oAnnotation.GetTitle.ToString)
                Debug.Print(oAnnotation.GetContents.ToString)
                Debug.Print(oAnnotation.GetFlags)

                Debug.Print(oAnnotation.HasFlag(1))
                Debug.Print(oAnnotation.HasFlag(2))
                Debug.Print(oAnnotation.HasFlag(3))
                Debug.Print(oAnnotation.HasFlag(4))

            End If

        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

> System.ArgumentException: 'Only one flag must be checked at once.'

Line that causes the error: `Debug.Print(oAnnotation.HasFlag(3))`

Debug results.

> JeEe 
>   Test annotation
>   4 
>   False 
>   False

Note: if I put the line `Debug.Print(oAnnotation.HasFlag(4))` in front of `Debug.Print(oAnnotation.HasFlag(3))` the error occurs still on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HasFlag` is documented as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the certain flag that specifies a characteristic of the annotation
    /// is in enabled state (see ISO-320001 12.5.3, "Annotation Flags").
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Checks if the certain flag that specifies a characteristic of the annotation
    /// is in enabled state (see ISO-320001 12.5.3, "Annotation Flags").
    /// This method allows only one flag to be checked at once, use constants listed in
    /// <see cref="SetFlag(int)"/>
    /// .
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="flag">
    /// an integer interpreted as set of one-bit flags. Only one bit must be set in this integer, otherwise
    /// exception is thrown.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>true if the given flag is in enabled state.</returns>
    public virtual bool HasFlag(int flag)
```

Thus, the parameter must be *an integer interpreted as set of one-bit flags. Only one bit must be set in this integer.* The integer 3 obviously has two bits set.

You appear to think that the parameter means something like *the nth flag* but it actually means *the flag with value n*.

So allowed values are 1, 2, 4, 8, ... but in particular not 3.